# How to remember and load selected date in UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date, uidatepicker, picker

I have a `UIDatePicker` that well, allows you to select a date (not time). I then save this `NSDate` and use display it in a label on a different view. However, when I load back the view with the `UIDatePicker`, if the user has already selected a date, I want it to show that selected date (using `NSDefaultPrefs`). How do I do this?

I know how to do it for a normal `UIPickerView`, but how does it work if it is a date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You save and restore the date however you want (in a `DB`, `NSDefaults`, etc). Once you have the date you want to set it to you just call [`-[UIDatePicker setDate:animated:]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDatePicker/setDate:animated:), so something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [datePicker setDate:myDate animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how its works.Am tried your solution but getting an error.