# Change App Date with Date Picker- xcode

Tags: xcode, date, datepicker, uidatepicker, picker

I just wanted to know if it would be possible to "trick" the app into thinking its a different date with uidatepicker. What I have is a uiwebview with a calendar based on query and i want to use a date picker from Xcode to change the date. When i go to settings o my device and change the date through settings, the webview also shows a different date so I basically want to know if this can be mimicked. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701012/how-to-remember-and-load-selected-date-in-uidatepicker).

Which basically gives the fine hint to use:

UIDatePicker's [`-(void) setDate: animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker%5FClass/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/instm/UIDatePicker/setDate%3Aanimated%3A) method.

You should just be able to pass the date you want to the datepicker in your app (which is an IBOutlet) and you should be okay to run with that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response:) Im confused still on how to implement the "my date" portion of the code though....thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you like to set the NSDate (which you then pass into UIDatePicker)?  There's a few ways to do it, and you can easily google up those techniques.  If you can't find an easy way (or a somewhat confusing way... i.e. using NSDateFormatter), let me know and I'll give you that answer as well. ;-)

Comment: Ok, so I've spent 2 days trying to find the answer to no avail :( Ok heres the best way I can describe it. I want the date picker to change the system date. I need this to change the date of my web view. Does that help? Thank You for staying with me.

Comment: what?  you want your date picker (built into your app) to change the date of the device????

Comment: I Guess...What I really want to accomplish is to get a UIDatePicker to change my calendar which is based off of jquery and implemented in a UIWebView.